# How to count .sh files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have to count all executable files- done it
and count files which are .sh files-  no idea how to do it.
Any help?
Here's my code:

```
c=0
d=0
    for f in /home/lenovo/*; do
        if [ -x "$f" ] ; then
           c=$(($c+1))
           if $f . name -iname = '*.sh'; then
             d=$(($d+1))
           fi
        fi
    done
    echo $c
    echo $d
```

Answer (score 1):

With a correct find command, you can do a correct and quick way to do this, for example :

```
find . -type f -name "*.sh"|wc -l
```

And you can set more arguements in find to be more efficient (for example *-maxdepth -mindepth* or *-ctime* or *-executable* or *-perm* that could be intersting too in you use case)

Answer (score 0):

Could it be as simple as `ls /home/lenovo/*.sh | wc -c`? Or do you have other
requirements?

This would count any file ending with .'sh' whether it is executable or not.